# Post real time output to Slack with bash script

Tags: python, bash, slack-api

I have a python script that I am executing with cron job. This script generates some output while executing and I wish to post it to Slack channel in real time.

Here is a bash script that I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file=logs_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M').txt

cd /path/to/script/run.py > /path/to/logs/${log_file} 2>&1 

cat /path/to/logs/${log_file} | while read LINE; do
  (echo "$LINE" | grep -e "Message" ) && curl -X POST --silent --data-urlencode \
    "payload={\"text\": \"$(echo $LINE | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx";
done
```

This scrip works but it of course posts all messages to slack once the python script has already been executed. Is there any way I could configure it so that messages would be sent to Slack in real time while the python script is still being executed?

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in the format string used by `date`? (Or perhaps, why does your log file have backslashes in the file name?). Is `cd` a typo for `python`?

Comment: @chepner Yes, it was a typo and backslashes were also not needed. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to read the output from your `run.py` script via process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file=logs_$(date '+\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M').txt

while read -r line ; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    (grep -e "Message" <<< "$line") && curl -X POST --silent --data-urlencode \
        "payload={\"text\": \"$(echo $line | sed "s/\"/'/g")\"}" "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx";
done < <(/path/to/script/run.py 2>&1) >> "$log_file"
```

It may also prove useful to paste your code into shellcheck.net and have a look at the suggested changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your script shouldn't work at all as you're not executing `run.py` but you're changing your working directory into it, so unless `run.py` is a directory, your script should fail.

Also, commands in bash scripting are executed sequentially, so if you launch your python command and then read the log, no wonder that you're not getting log lines in real time.

What i would do is using some pipes and xargs:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/script/run.py | grep -e "Message" | sed "s/\"/'/g" | xargs -I{} curl -L -X POST --silent --data-urlencode 'payload={"text":"{}"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx
```

I've added `-L` to the curl command because `hooks.slack.com` makes a redirect to `api.slack.com` and without that flag `curl` will stop after the `302` instead of following the `Location` header in the response.